# Angular 2: String interpolation with function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I am developing my first Angular app and having trouble with string interpolation.

I have a component which contains the following element:

```
`<span>{{action.getText()}}</span>`
```

action is of Type Action which has the following method:

```
getText(): String { return "Test"; }
```

The variable action is defined correctly since I can access properties via {{}} without a problem. e.g. `{{action.title}}`

So my question is, is this even possible to access this function and if yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How `action` looks like? I usually use `string` datatype not `String`

Comment: Try with a propery getter `get text() { return "Test"; }` and `{{action.text}}`. Work only if the action object come from your component ts file or from a local variable defined with the # tag.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas i now have `get text() { return "Test";}` and `{{action.text}}` in my component. But there is now no text shown (at least it doesn't crash anymore). The variable action is defined in the associated Component file

Comment: @AvinashRaj this class only holds a few variables and this method. What's the difference between `string` and `String`?

Comment: And for general understanding: So, it's not possible to call a function this way? Let's say, my class Action has a date property and i want to display the minutes value. Then i cannot write `{{action.date.getMinutes()}}`

Comment: Why do you think `ation` contains a method `getText()`. Is the typo (missing `c`) only in your question?

Comment: Yes, it's just a typo in my question. I just corrected it. The variable is of type Action which contains a method getText()

Comment: @Luca Note that the text property getter should be inside the action class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert it to a property:

```
get text(): string { return "Test"; }
```

Your template becomes:

```
<span>{{ation.text}}</span>
```

Comment: Scratch that. You can convert to a property, but binding to a function result actually works as expected.

Comment: Now, it shows nothing at all where the `<span>` should be

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: So, in your comment you're saying that `action.getText()` should actually work fine?

Comment: With the function call `action.getText()` the application crashes. With the getter, there's nothing in the console

Comment: What does "crashes" mean exactly? What is the message?

Comment: This is the output on my console:
`Object { __zone_symbol__error: Error, fileName: Getter, lineNumber: Getter, columnNumber: Getter, message: Getter, name: Getter, stack: Getter, originalStack: Getter, zoneAwareStack: Getter, toString: createMethodProperty/props[key].value(), 4 weitere… }  zone.js:518:9
 consoleError http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:518:9
 drainMicroTaskQueue http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:532:25
 ZoneTask/this.invoke http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:25`

Comment: I think your `zone.js` is busted. If you update, you should see the actual error. Meanwhile, when you make the property change and place a breakpoint, can you confirm it's being called? I think you have something else going on.

Comment: Ok, i just found out, what is wrong. Apparently, the data i have is not properly casted to type `Action`. I get the data as JSON from my Server and then call `result => result.json() as Action[]` as advised https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html here. This apparently does not cast the data to type `Action[]` but to type `Object[]` which explains why i can't do any function calls at all. When i mock the data as `Action[]` every one of the proposed solutions works

Answer (score 0):

You refer to `action.title`, but `ation.getText()`. Certainly a typo?

```
<span>{{action.getText()}}</span>
```

Comment: `ation` is a typo, which I have now corrected. The reference to `action.title` should just show, that the variable is defined correctly, since i can access this property.